# Tidyverse in R: Cannot load package

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am having trouble loading the tidyverse package in R 4.0.4.

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘dplyr’ 1.0.2 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required
```

I then try to install dplyr thinking it will complete the update required and get the following.

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/..../Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
also installing the dependency ‘vctrs’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
dplyr  1.0.4  1.0.5              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.case.edu/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/vctrs_0.3.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1236025 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.case.edu/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/dplyr_1.0.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1329967 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘vctrs’
Warning: restored ‘vctrs’
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
Warning: restored ‘dplyr’

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\TEMP\RtmpwxZiEB\downloaded_packages
Warning messages:
1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\....\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\.....\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\.....\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll to C:\Users\.....\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\dplyr\libs\x64\dplyr.dll: Permission denied
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Completely exit out of R and then try again.  When you restart R, the updated version of Dplyr should be available.

Comment: try uninstalling the packages and reinstalling it.